# How to change getElementbyId to getElementsbyClassName

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the value of colspan using the below code but its only working for January. It should work for both January and February. By clicking the button the value of the colspan attribute, from 2 to 1, of td with id "myTd".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to change the value of the colspan attribute, from 2 to 1, of td with id "myTd".</p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="myTd" colspan="2">January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="myTd" colspan="2">February</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br> 

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myTd").colSpan = "1";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `id="myTd"` IDs *must* be unique.  As such, DOM methods such as getElementById or selectors such as `#myId` will only find the first, as they expect there to be only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your issue is because you've repeated the same `id` on multiple elements, which is invalid. `id` must be unique within the DOM. Change these to common `class` attributes.

From there you can use `querySelectorAll()` and loop through the resulting collection to update their `colspan`:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  document.querySelectorAll(".myTd").forEach(el => el.colSpan = "1");
});
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to change the value of the colspan attribute, from 2 to 1, of td with id "myTd".</p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="myTd" colspan="2">January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="myTd" colspan="2">February</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>

<button>Try it</button>
```

Note the use of `addEventListener()` in the above example. This is an unobtrusive event handler bound in JS code, not HTML. It's much better practice over using inline `onclick` attributes.